# Refactor C# code for creating XML to not use intermediate dictionary

Tags: c#

If have the following code that via an SQL query retrieves data from a database in the form:

```
Id      subschemaName  locusName
MLST    MLST           LMO0558
MLST    MLST           LMO0563
MLVST   MLVST          LMO1305
MLVST   MLVST          LMO1089
```

And I want to turn this into an XML like:

```xml
<ResponseSubschemas>
    <organism>LMO</organism>
    <Subschemas>
        <Subschema>
            <id>MLST</id>
            <name>MLST</name>
            <loci>
                <locus>LMO0558</locus>
                <locus>LMO0563</locus>
            </loci>
        </Subschema>
        <Subschema>
            <id>MLVST</id>
            <name>MLVST</name>
            <loci>
                <locus>LMO1305</locus>
                <locus>LMO1089</locus>
            </loci>
        </Subschema>
    </Subschemas>
</ResponseSubschemas>
```

I do this by using a dictionary but it is the first time I'm using C# and I'm sure there must be a more efficient way of doing this in one go?

```
string subschemaSQL =   "SELECT subschema.Id, subschema.name as subschemaName, locus.Name as locusName " + 
                        "FROM subschema " +
                        "LEFT JOIN subschemamembers ON subschemamembers.SubSchemaID = subschema.PrimKey " +
                        "LEFT JOIN locus ON subschemamembers.LocusID = locus.ID " +
                        "WHERE  subschema.OrganismID = ? " +
                        "ORDER BY subschema.Id, locusName";

XElement rootNode = new XElement("ResponseSubschemas", 
    new XElement("organism", organismID),
    new XElement("Subschemas"));
XElement subschemasNode = rootNode.Element("Subschemas");

DbDataReader subschemaReader = conn.Query(subschemaSQL, organismID);

Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
while (subschemaReader.Read())
{
    string subschemaDbID = (string)subschemaReader["Id"];
    XElement subschemaNode = new XElement("Subschema",
        new XElement("id", subschemaDbID),
        new XElement("name", subschemaReader["subschemaName"])
    );
    subschemasNode.Add(subschemaNode);
    string locusName = (string)subschemaReader["locusName"];
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(subschemaDbID))
    {
        dictionary[subschemaDbID].Add(locusName);
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary.Add(subschemaDbID, new List<string> { locusName });
    }
}



IEnumerable<XElement> subschemaNodes = from element in
                                       subschemasNode.Elements("Subschema")
                                       select element;
foreach (XElement subschemaNode in subschemaNodes)
{
    string subschemaID = subschemaNode.Element("id").Value;
    XElement lociNode = new XElement("loci");
    foreach (string locusName in dictionary[subschemaID])
    {
        XElement locusNode = new XElement("locus", locusName);
        lociNode.Add(locusNode);
    }
    subschemaNode.Add(lociNode);

}

responseXml = rootNode.ToString();
```

Comment: You could certainly be using Linq-to-Sql rather than hard coding sql strings. The result could then be easily transformed into Linq-to-Xml objects, though I definitely don't understand why you'd want to copy a database to xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your data is already sorted you definitely don't need to use a dictionary. You can just accumulate `loci` and then whenever the `id` or `subschemaId` rolls over you write them all out. That wouldn't be a huge change from what you've got. But honestly, what you've got is a bit confusing because you're trying to do several things at once. Namely:

- Read from the database and parse the data
- Determine when you've read an entire set of data
- Write it all to XML

It would be easier to figure out what's going on by separating those things out from each other. It might also make your life easier if you ever want to do anything more complex with this data than just dumping it to XML. So let's just do a little rewrite.

To start with, let's create a class to hold each of those `Subschema` elements. (Honestly `Subschema` seems like a confusing name to me, it seems like maybe `OrganismLocations` or `OrganismSightings` might be more descriptive, but let's just stick with `Subschema`.)

```
public class Subschema{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<string> Loci {get;set;}

    public Subschema(){
        Loci = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Now, let's write a function to parse the database records out into a list of `Subschema` objects. This is basically doing what I said earlier - tracking `loci` until we hit a new `id` or `subschemaName`. We're using C# iterators (that's the `yield return` syntax) to make this a little bit cleaner.

```
private IEnumerable<Subschema> ParseSubschemas(DbDataReader subschemaReader){
    if(!subschemaReader.HasRows){
        yield break;
    }

    Subschema subschema = null;

    while(subschemaReader.Read()){
        //If we've rolled over to a new ID or SubschemaName, start a new set of sightings
        if(subschema != null && (subschema.Id != (string)subschemaReader["id"] || subschema.Name != (string)subschemaReader["subschemaName"])){
            yield return subschema;
            subschema = null;
        }

        if(subschema == null){
            subschema = new Subschema(){
                Id = (string)subschemaReader["id"],
                Name = (string)subschemaReader["subschemaName"]
            };
        }

        subschema.Loci.Add((string)subschemaReader["locusName"]);
    }

    //yield the last subschema
    yield return subschema;
}
```

So now we have a nice, clean list of the data you need to output. Basically we've handled the first and second bullets from my list, so all that's left is turning that into XML. There's probably a cleaner way of doing this than using `XElement`s directly, but let's just stick with it for the moment. But again, let's stick all the logic in a nice clean function.

```
private XElement SerializeSubSchemasToXml(string organismId, IEnumerable<Subschema> sightings){
    XElement rootNode = new XElement("ResponseSubschemas", 
        new XElement("organism", organismId),
        new XElement("Subschemas"));
    XElement subschemasNode = rootNode.Element("Subschemas");

    //Turn each Sighting into an XElement, and append to the subschemas
    foreach(var sighting in sightings){
        var subschemaElem = new XElement("Subschema", 
                                new XElement("id", sighting.Id),
                                new XElement("name", sighting.Name),
                                new XElement("Loci", sighting.Loci.Select(l => new XElement("locus", l)))        
                            );

        subschemasNode.Add(subschemaElem);
    }

    return rootNode;
}
```

Pretty straightforward here. We could've written this more succinctly, probably even in a (really big) one liner, but this strikes a reasonable balance with clarity, I think.

So, now we just have to put those two together...

```
private string ReadSubschemasAsXml(){
    string organismId = "FOO";
    string subschemaSQL =   "SELECT subschema.Id, subschema.name as subschemaName, locus.Name as locusName " + 
        "FROM subschema " +
        "LEFT JOIN subschemamembers ON subschemamembers.SubSchemaID = subschema.PrimKey " +
        "LEFT JOIN locus ON subschemamembers.LocusID = locus.ID " +
        "WHERE  subschema.OrganismID = ? " +
        "ORDER BY subschema.Id, locusName";

    using(DbDataReader subschemaReader = conn.Query(subschemaSQL, organismId)){
        IEnumerable<Subschema> sightings = ParseSubschemas(subschemaReader);
        XElement xelem = SerializeSubSchemasToXml(organismId, sightings);
        return xelem.ToString();
    }
}
```

That last function isn't really a thing of beauty either - it's got kind of a lot going on. But it's definitely better. I also added a `using` statement around your `DbDataReader`, which is just a handy way of making sure that it gets `Dispose()`d properly.

By the way, I put up a [DotNetFiddle of the whole thing](http://dotnetfiddle.net/6m6iIe). It doesn't work because I don't have a database to use, but it might be easier to read there.

Comment: I guess you could use the XmlSerializer class to serialize to XML.

Comment: @dreza, yes you could. You'd have to create another class to handle the wrapper XML structure, but it wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Your `ParseSubschemas()` will return a sequence containing `null` when the input is empty, I think that's wrong.

Comment: @svick - good point. I modified it to return an empty enumerable instead.